# Не подключается файл-css

Tags: html, css

Хотелось бы узнать что не так с этим кодом? Почему он не видит файл Test.css?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<HTML> 
<head> 
    <title> TEST </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css" /> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td> 
            </td> 

            <td> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td > 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</body> 
</HTML>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css" />
```

Вот сам файл-css:

```
TABLE{ 
border: 2; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
}
```

[image: Таблица, которую хочу получить.]Все файлы лежат в одной папке!!

Comment: может нужно втулить /

Comment: втулить в href?

Comment: а почему  считаешь, что не работает?   и что дожно быть по твоему?

Comment: Переименуйте файл в  test.css в link напишите href="test.css".  В файле напишите body{ background:red; }  Зайдите на сайт  нажмите ctrl+f5

Comment: `border: 2` чего? 2 яблока? Может, вы хотели написать `border: 2px`?

Comment: @Belyash, привет из 90-х видимо потому, что сейчас табличной версткой почти не пользуются для разработки сайтов. ну или в очень специфичных местах (например вывод таблицы, как бы банально это не звучало).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
```

У меня работает? если у тебя не получится, то не знаю, у тебя что-то с ПК или с хостингом

Answer (score 0):

Если используете *nix хостинг, то проверьте имя файла. Большие и маленькие буквы: Test.css и test.css - разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

А файл html и css находятся в одной папке? Если нет то нужно указать путь к css от html. Например есть папка "Проект" если открыть папку будет файл с html и папка "CSS". В папки CSS есть файл CSS с именем test.css. Значит в html нужно указать путь так:

Answer (score 0):

У свойства `border` должно быть указано значение `solid`(сплошная линия) для отображения границы. Например:

```
table { 
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}

td {
    border: 2px solid #000; 
}
```